# RequestBody handling a JSON containing Strings and a List

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm sending a post request from the client to the server. The body of the post request looks like this:

```
        ...
        body: JSON.stringify
            ({
                command: 'someString',
                dataFields: setDataList()
            })
        ...
```

while the "setDataList()" returns the following structure:
[ {…}, {…}, {…}, ..., {…} ]

```
        [0: {type: "_header_", label: "upload"}
        1: {type: "_image_", name: "data:image/jpeg;base64", value: "base64 encoded string", label: "someImage.JPG"}
        2: {...}]
```

I'm having issues processing the content of the "dataFields" key at the server. Currently, the SpringBoot applicaiton looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(
consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},
produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public void postBody(@RequestBody ManageRequest manageRequest) {
  ...
}
```

and "ManageRequest" like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class ManageRequest {
  private String accountId;
  private String command;
  private String transactionId;
  private List<String> dataFields;

  public String getAccountId() {
    return accountId;
  }

  public String getTransactionId() {
    return transactionId;
  }

  public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
    this.transactionId = transactionId;
  }

  public void setAccountId(String accountId) {
    this.accountId = accountId;
  }

  public String getCommand() {
    return command;
  }

  public void setCommand(String command) {
    this.command = command;
  }

  public List<String> getDataFieldList() {
    return dataFields;
  }

  public void setDataFieldList(List<String> dataList) {
    this.dataFields = dataList;
  }
```

}

I'm not experienced in handling such requests with Java. My goal would be to extract the content of the "dataFields" like this: "dataFields[0], dataFields[1], ..." and allocate them to a new List to add to a post request.
At the moment, the list seems to be empty when arriving at the end point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems is with the List.
The server is waiting for a List of Strings but you are sending a List of objects with fields that are Strings.

```
private List<String> dataFields; // This property is a List of string not a list of "dataFields"
```

You should create a class DataField and it would looks like this

```
public class DataField{
    
    private String type;
    private String label;
    private String name;
    .
    .
    .

}
```

And then in your ManageRequest class you should do like this:

```
 public class ManageRequest {
    private String accountId;
    private String command;
    private String transactionId;
    private List<DataField> dataFields;

    //Getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I've added a class and replaced the "String". Nevertheless, logging the dataFields yields me "null". I'm sending the post request over Postman including: 
...
"dataFields": [{
"type": "_image",
"label": "example"
}],
...

I feel like my setter and getter functions do not work as intended. For the other attributes with type String it works fine.

Comment: Could you send me the body of your JSON that you are using for the request?

Comment: Actually, I messed up the names of the getter and setter methods. I had to name them the exact same way as the attributes (+ "get" or "set" in front ofc). So now I do get the values.
Thank you for your help.